# Did Dialup Modem use closed or open loop power/volume control? How did they determine Tx level?

Tags: audio, digital-communications, voice, feedback, communication-standard

I have been reading about dialup modems, but one thing I cannot seem to find out about is how implementers determined optimal transmit power/volume. Is this part of the echo cancelation framework? The block diagrams I have seen describing echo cancelation don't seem to mention it.
[image]

Comment: By the way, that figure looks like an ADSL modem, not a dialup modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did Dialup Modem use closed or open loop power/volume control?

Yes.

> How did they determine Tx level?

"Dialup Modem" is a very big term that spans > 50 years of technological development.

Early modems for landline telephone very pretty plain binary FSK. So, there wasn't much use for any fine-grained volume control.

V.90 modems sense the channel during connection establishment, and equalize (and in reality probably re-adjust during operation). Of course, this also means they'll also adjust power / amplitude to get the most information through the channel at minimum distortion, power consumption and crosstalk.

Now, you've got me reading the V.34 standard (which I had before, but because of something else):

V.34 already introduced negotiation of TX power, so that's a closed-loop control.

But, honestly, for something that has *very* modified QAM constellations ("superconstellations") and Trellis coding since at least the early 1990s, talking about "open or closed loop TX power control" feels like asking whether a Boeing 747 autopilot has "closed or open loop altitude control"; it ignores that TX power is just one of *very* many adjusted parameters that effect the waveshape.

> but one thing I cannot seem to find out about is how implementers determined optimal transmit power/volume.

The V.34 standard is freely available at the ITU, maybe check that, it defines how the transmitting modem learns from the receiving modem that it should be adjusting power.

Of course, that standard doesn't define how that modem determines it would be better to reduce power – that's up to the individual implementation. But we know why you'd want to reduce power: too much power is bad because it drives amplifiers into nonlinearity, and forces modems on adjacent lines that are subject to crosstalk to transmit stronger themselves, thus increasing interference for us.

Hence, the receiving V.34 modem will use DSP to determine the power in the intermodulation products in the L1 and L2 line probing signals. L1 seems to be made for this: it has tones in a regular 150 Hz raster, with a few left out. That's where you don't want to "hear" anything if there's no intermodulation due to nonlinearity.
L2 is the same signal, but 6 dB weaker - and from the difference in things you shouldn't hear but are hearing, you can calculate (for a sufficiently simple model of your nonlinearities) how far you'd want to reduce the power, before the improvement in distortion becomes less beneficial than the decrease in SNR becomes detrimental.